# REST API Security and CrossPlatform

Tags: node.js, api, security, rest, cross-platform

I'm working on rest api with node.js. I create jwt-token in /signup endpoint. Then send this token every ios-app,windowsphone-app requests in Authoriziton header. So api try find user which contain this token. If its have then return responses.

I'm worry about security. Everybody will monitoring api addresses for create user and get token then use this token for all endpoints. So will post data an infinate number to other schemas and application be garbage, dies.

How can prevent this situation ? Native iOS,Windows Phone apps and Web Site used to this api. Whats the best way handling security and user management somelike cross platform application api's ? Is there good documentation for this sturucture ?

There is user scheme.

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    token:String,
    favorites:[favorites],
    local : {
        username:String,
        email: String,
        password: String,
        sex:Number
    },
    facebook: {
        id:String,
        token:String,
        email:String,
        name:String
    },
    lists:[{listid:String,insertdate:Date}]
});
```

Every endpoint control authorization like this

```
function ensureAuthorized(req, res, next) {
        var bearerToken;
        console.log(req.headers);
        var bearerHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
        if (typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined') {

            req.token = bearerHeader;
            User.findOne({'token':bearerHeader},function(err,currentUser){
                if(err)
                    res.json({success:false,description:err});

                console.log("current" + currentUser);
                if(currentUser)
                {
                    req.user = currentUser;
                    next();
                }
                else
                {
                    res.status(403).end();
                }
            });
        } else {
            res.status(403).end();
        }
    }
```

Thank you all.